# Export and Import models/pipeline as JSON using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a fitted pipeline in pyspark. I want to convert the fitted pipeline into JSON and store it in the database so another person can fetch it from the database and convert it again into a fitted pipeline spark object.

I am using jupyter-notebook to run the spark

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import GBTClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

data = (spark.read.option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true") 
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("./data/data.csv")).drop("id")

reduced_numeric_cols = ["account_length", "number_vmail_messages", "total_day_calls",
                        "total_day_charge", "total_eve_calls", "total_eve_charge",
                        "total_sales_calls", "total_sales_calls", "total_sales_charge"]


label_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'quantity', outputCol = 'label')
plan_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'sales_plan', outputCol = 'sales_plan_indexed')

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols = ['sales_plan_indexed'] + reduced_numeric_cols,
    outputCol = 'features')

classifier = GBTClassifier(labelCol = 'label', featuresCol = 'features')

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[plan_indexer, label_indexer, assembler, classifier])

(train, test) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3]).

model = pipeline.fit(train)

// I want to save the model as a JSON object in file

// Read the JSON file and convert it into again the fitted model
```

Comment: Fitted pipelines can be saved with `model.save()` and loaded using `PipelineModel.load()`. The storage format is a directory with metadata and a separate directory for each stage. If you want to store everything in one single JSON file, you may need to implement your own reader and writer, if that's even possible.

Comment: Thanks, @HristoIliev Right now I am. doing the same as you suggested above by using save and load but I need a JSON object.